# Links being wrapped HTTP and not HTTPS

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ssl, hyperlink

The links in our emails within Marketing Cloud after they are sent are being wrapped with tracking that uses HTTP and not HTTPS, which is what we have configured with our SSL

The links would look like this:
http://click.email.domain.com/

Is there a way in SF to configure these link wraps?

Comment: Is this a Marketing Cloud question? Email Templates? Apex emails? Something else? How are these links generated? Please be more descriptive to we can assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple reasons for this:

1. The SSL configuration was done for a (different) Private Domain and not your SAP domain
2. SSL was only configured for image URLs and not for click tracking subdomain (these require one SSL cert each) on your SAP domain
3. The emails you are looking at are triggered send, and these might need republishing before the URL protocol change takes effect.

My best advise, if you are sure none of the above apply, it to raise a ticket with Salesforce support.